# Opening ECW files in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ecw

I'm trying to open an ECW file in Arcmap 10.5 but I can't seem to find a way to do so. I tried to download a plug in but since I'm not the administrator of the computer I need a password that I don't have and the person that has it won't be back anytime soon.

So what are my options to be able to open these ECW files with arcgis 10.5 without having to download or install something new ? (I can try to download and install something if you have an idea but I doubt it will work).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to install anything, ArcMap has ECW read support by default.

[See here for the full list of supported raster formats.](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/manage-data/raster-and-images/supported-raster-dataset-file-formats.htm)

Comment: Thank you, I did find this page but then do you know why I'm not able to open this files ? is there something I need to activate to be able to read them properly ?

Comment: There was this post over at geonet https://community.esri.com/thread/190404-arcmap-104-wont-open-ecw#comment-667152

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue.

Found a solution: - Download the ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.2 Enhanced Compression Wavelet (ECW) Support Patch (https://support.esri.com/en-us/patches-updates/2022/arcgis-desktop-10-8-2-enhanced-compression-wavelet-ecw-7991).

After installation I was immediately able to open the ECW files.